# Sonarqube 5.1 fail to send an email

Tags: email, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

My sonarqube is working fine with issue auto assigning and everything. But there are no emails sent. I do not have the issue assign plugin installed.
Test email sent from the

> settings -> general -> email

is working fine.
What can be the probable issue?
I can't find any email related log in sonar log also. And Im using jenkins.

I know there is not much to go on. But can you guide me. What can it be that I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can set email notification through user's profile setting. It is in top right side corner where user id is displayed.